# Deleting lines from a file with binary pattern strings

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I've got two files. File A contains text written in N lines, and File B contains a binary pattern string of 0 and 1 that has N length too.

I want to delete the lines from File A that has the same line number that the one on File B that contains a 0.

I've read that it might be a good idea to do it with awk, but I don't have any idea of how to use it.

Files are very long, like 2000 lines for example (they are video traces)

For example:

File A:

```
Line 1: 123456
Line 2: 789012
Line 3: 345678
Line 4: 901234
```

File B:

```
Line 1: 1
Line 2: 0
Line 3: 0
Line 4: 1
```

After the execution:

File A:

```
Line 1: 123456
Line 2: 901234
```

Comment: "Line 1:" etc. isn't really part of the files, is it?

Comment: That's right, Line 1 and etc are not part of my file, the line starts after the : (it was just to clarify what I want to do). Thanks for all of your answers! I will start to working on it today, and tell you which I finally chose. A lot of interesting proposals!!!

Comment: And I want it to do for every file independent of what contains each line I want it to be deleted if the same line number has a 0 on the other file, because the video traces will be different If I use a different video. I think that you have considered it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `paste` and `cut` for this:

```
paste fileB fileA | grep '^1' | cut -f2-
```

- `paste fileB fileA` - pastes file contents side by side, delimited by a tab
- `grep '^1'` - filters that lines that start with 1
- `cut -f2-` - extracts the content that we need

Both `cut` and `paste` use tab as the default delimiter.

This is very similar to [Benjamin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611082/6862601) solution.  A small advantage here is that it would work even if fileA were to have more than one field per line.

Comment: Good point - my solution breaks if there is a tab in `fileA`, and I'd have to use a different delimiter for `paste` and `cut`.

Comment: Finally I've used this one, but I wanted to save it after deleting the line, so I modify it to: paste fileB fileA | grep '^1' | cut -f2- > finalFile.txt

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [decorate – filter – undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern:

```
paste fileA fileB | grep -v '0$' | cut -f1
```

This prints the lines of each file next to each other (`paste`), then filters the lines that end with `0` (`grep`), then removes the lines from the second file (`cut`).

This breaks if `fileA` contains the delimiter used for `paste` and `cut` (a tab by default). To avoid that, we could either swap the files (see [codeforester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611086/3266847)) or resort to something like

```
paste fileA fileB | sed -n '/1$/s/\t.$//p'
```

(if line ends with `1`, remove tab and last character, then print) or

```
paste fileA fileB | grep -Po '.*(?=\t1$)'
```

(match only lines ending in `1`, use zero-width look-ahead to exclude tab and `1` from match); the last solution requires a grep that supports Perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE) such as GNU grep.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of interesting answers here. Here's a bash one:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 line; IFS= read -r -u4 bool; do 
    ((bool == 1)) && printf "%s\n" "$line"
done 3<fileA 4<fileB
```

This will be much slower than other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Line 1:` etc don't really exist in your input files all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} a[FNR]' fileB fileA
```

Comment: And I've used this one on Windows, because I have "awk" installed. Thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

A single `awk` command can read from both files.

```
awk '(getline flag < "fileB") > 0 && flag' fileA
```

After reading each line from `fileA`, read a line from `fileB` into a variable flag and test if its integer value is true or not. For true values, the line from `fileA` is printed.

Depending on your version of `awk`, you may need to use `int(flag)` or `flag+0` to force the value to be treated as an integer rather than an ordinary non-empty string.

Comment: Hm. I added the call to `int` because (at least in the BSD version on macOS I used for testing) every line was being printed when I used `flag` alone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between `getline flag < "fileB"` and `(getline flag < "fileB") > 0`.

Comment: Regarding `getline`, clearly I just need to read the documentation more carefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

another `paste`/`awk` solution. If tab appears in data find another delimiter.

```
paste file2 file1 | awk -F'\t' '$1{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** @codeforester's comment if `Line 1` or `Line 2` are not part of your File1 and File2 then following may help.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} $0!=0{print a[FNR]}' filea fileb
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Reading fileb file first and then reading filea then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if($0!=0){a[FNR]=$0};next} a[FNR]' fileb filea
```

---

---

Solution 1st's alternative in case OP has string(s) line1, line2 in his/her files.

Following `awk` may help here too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$NF;
  next}
$NF!=0{
  printf("%s%s\n","Line " ++count": ",a[FNR])
}' filea fileb
```

Comment: I think "Line 1:" etc., isn't a part of the files.

Comment: @codeforester, cool, sure added EDIT solution too now for case where line string is not part of files.

Comment: here `$NF!=0` can be replaced with `$NF`

Answer (score 0):

`paste` and `sed` combo:

```
paste -d'\n' fileB fileA | sed -n '/^1$/{n;p}'
123456
901234
```

You interleave the files:

```
1
123456
0
789012
0
345678
1
901234
```

Then you use `sed` to print the lines that follow directly a line that has only a `1`. However this will not behave properly if you have entries that are composed only of a `1` in the `fileA`. If it is the case then you have to use the following `sed` command that takes into account if we are currently processing an odd/even line:

```
paste -d'\n' fileB fileA | sed -n '1~2{/^1$/{n;p}}'
```